# Coefficients of (linearly displaced) 2nd order terms in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a expression in Sympy somewhat like

`poly = a1*(x1+d1+x2)**2 + a2*(x2+d2)**2 + c + t**2`

, but with many more terms. I want to find the coefficients of the quadratic terms containing any of my `x1,x2,...`.

The options I've tried:

- I have tried with using `poly.coeff(x1,n=2)` for my different `xi` but since the terms are not pure polynomials in `xi` it yields `0`.
- Expanding the polynomial terms before is not an option, since it involves mixing the coefficients `ai`.
- looking at all quadratic terms is not an option, since there are terms that are quadratic in symbols other than `xi`, such as `t` in my example above.

How can I use sympy to get a list of the expressions/symbols/values `a1, a2`and so on?

Comment: What do you mean by extracting the coefficients?

Comment: slight edit of the question. I want to get the expressions/symbols `a1,a2` so that I can `ask(Q.positive(a1)` for example.